# How to make footer buttons fixed in native android application?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-ndk

In my project i'm using buttons in the footer, when any text entered in the text box the qwerty keyboard opened and at the same time the buttons changed it's footer position and display above the keyboard. Here is my code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="#4D4D4D"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-55dp"  >
 <Button android:id="@+id/signout" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#4D4D4D"
        android:text="Add Spot"
        android:textSize="15px"
        android:padding="8px">
</Button>    
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: do you want to fix the button at bottom?

Comment: @himanshu yes i want to keep the footer button fixed

Comment: i have post the answer see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan"`

in manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

in your manifest.xml set your activity's windowSoftInputMode to state unchanged.

Comment: i added himanshu's code in manifest file and now it's working

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a parameter in your activity tag in your manifest file

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

And your button is remain in bottom when you open keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:background="#4D4D4D"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="55dp"
android:layout_marginTop="-55dp"  >

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button android:id="@+id/signout" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#4D4D4D"
    android:text="Add Spot"
    android:textSize="15px"
    android:padding="8px">
    </Button>    

</LinearLayout>
```